# Example of a discrete-time martingale with uncorrelated, but dependent, increments

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, independence, correlation

Can you give me an example for a martingale with discrete time parameter, where the increments are not independent, just uncorrelated?

Comment: Consider a sequence $X_1, X_2 \cdots$ of [uncorrelated dependent mean-zero Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent). The martingale could be defined by $Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$.

Comment: That's right. After I had written this question, I realized that a martingale has uncorrelated increments (because of its definition), so every martingale obtained by summing up uncorrelated increments with zero expectation is a martingale. But it is not necessary have to be a martingale with independent increments. For a second I thought every martingale with discrete time parameter has independent increments, and that is what I really wanted to know whit this question. I just realized it is nonsense, so it is not a good question. Thank you for your answer anyway...